# Mageplaza menu does not shown on Sidebar

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, smtp, magento-2-commerce

I just started to learn how to use Magento 2, I have just installed it on my local laptop. The instalation has been successfully completed and then I decide to install SMTP support for email notification so I decided to use Mageplaza SMTP. I have followed all the instruction from the document https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/user-guide.html, but unfortunately I still unable to get it work, I don't even having this on my sidebar menu.

[image]

[image]

As you can see I have this extension downloaded and installed (I am using Composer to install it).

Anyone know how to make it work and shown in my sidebar menu?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think it does not supported by Magento 2.3 yet https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/issues/129 maybe somebody can help me regarding this

Comment: To configure it go to stores -> configuration -> Mageplaze in the sidebar -> SMTP to configure.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran hey, you are right, why not put that as Answer so I can vote that up?

Comment: Have you run all the commands ??<br/> php bin/magento setup:upgrade php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Hi mate I finally got the answer, It has been there but I need to configure it so it can be shown on the sidebar menu. : Stores -> Configuration -> MAGEPLAZA EXTENSIONS -> Information -> [General Configuration ->Enable Mageplaza Menu -> Yes] -> Save Config.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153312)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to configure an extension,

> Go to stores -> configuration -> MAGEPLAZA EXTENSIONS -> Information -> [General Configuration ->Enable Mageplaza Menu -> Yes] -> Save Config

and if you're not sure about the menu and the configuration in the sense. Please check the below file understand better.

Go to app/code/Mageplaza/Smtp/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

that is where all the configuration stuffs will be defined.

Hope this helps.